# Extremely slow download speed, could my modem be causing it?

Tags: router, performance, internet, modem, isp

First off all I want to thank everyone who is reading this.

This will be a long problem so I really hope someone has an answer, as my ISP doesn't.

For over a month we have been experiencing extremely slow speeds at night. When I say slow, speeds of 0-1 if we are lucky. I have called my ISP numerous times and they don't seem to see any problems with our equipment. `"Your modem signals look excellent. Your issue seems to be isolated so I will put a ticket on your account."` I can't begin to tell you how many times I have heard that line.

They have had at least 5 techs come out, none of which can figure out what the problem is. Since the problem is only at night it makes everything a little awkward. They went around tightening all the splitters, looking at the cable etc. They said it should be fine, your signals look great. I speed test that night, speed of 0.09. I call in, and the circle begins. That's all I do with them is go in circles!

They finally came out this week and replaced the line from the pole to our house thinking that the line was faulty. That night we still had issues. They then thought someone was piggy backing off our WiFi, so I went and changed all the passwords, the router configuration page passwords, everything, and here I am, still having issues. I have reached out to TONS of people for help, none of which have an answer.

I asked if my modem/router could be causing the speed loss as we are on a docsis1. I don't know much about docsis but a tech that came out said they had just upgraded everything from a docsis1 to a docsis3. I asked if our router being a docsis1 could have problems communicating with the new upgrade. He said that should be an issue. They say all the signals look fine, yet we are still having an issue. Over a month now and no conclusion, that's why I am reaching out to anyone who reads this.

PLEASE HELP! I've talked to people and they think we are being throttled. Our company has on their homepage, `"no throttling, no caps, no limit"` so that cant be the issue can it? I'll post my router and modem details below, if anyone reads this and needs more info please ask. I'm just really frustrated and want everything back to normal. Thanks!

**Router** Cisco Linksys E1500
**Modem** Scientific Atlantica Cable Internet.

Comment: I used to have a similar problem (slow speeds at particular times of day) with my ISP. Based on the timing of the slowdowns, I guessed that my ISP was just unable to provide their advertised speeds during peak usage. It is the only explanation I can think of that would explain why the issue only occurred at certain times of day.

Comment: Without any units it's hard to answer this question

Comment: What other information do you need? I'll do my best to retrieve it. I'm pretty desperate for any help.

Comment: Name all web-capable devices and residents in the house. What devices are you using to go online? Do you have a better timeline than at night? Sounds like your being 'throttled' by your neighbors when they get home and start downloading or is someone in your house using torrents?

Comment: We have 2 laptops, 4 iphones, 1 ipod, and 1 kindle. I just recently changed our network password, and our router configuration password so that can't be the problem, and no one in the house uses torrents. The time line i have noticed is it usually gets really bad around 10pm. These last couple of days it has been getting worse earlier. Could a modem show it has good signals, yet cause a speed drop this bad? We should be around 10mbps and were getting 0.

Comment: At 1PM you can get 10mbps on multiple devices simultaneously? Then your hardware is fine. Next time it happens, power down all of those devices except one and try it. Repeat using the others one at a time. Stream something on both laptops, if it won't your router might be bad and not sending out IPs correctly or a DNS issue making only one connection at a time available. Are you absolutely sure about the downloading\streaming habits of the other 3 people in the house? It really sounds like someone is bandwidth hogging.

Comment: A couple of them may watch netflix or youtube occasionally but that hasnt been a problem before, we upgraded our speed because 6 wasnt enough for our family. when we were at 10 people could watch netflix while others could etc. No one in our family uses torrents or download huge amounts of files etc. I'll try your steps though, ill power off all the other devices and leave 1 up, and test it. The thing is its hard to tell how it is during the day, everyone is at school/work.

Comment: Also try plugging a laptop directly into the modem to insure its not your router.

Comment: i have tried that. i bypassed the router and was connected directly to the modem, still had the same speed issues. Thank you for your help by the way, it really means a lot.

Comment: No prob. Anyone on your block have the same ISP? If you could verify that it works well during the day, then you could be routed through some switch gear that gets over loaded at night. Hopefully it is a bad modem.

Comment: the tech that has come out a couple of times has said that there are no other problems up the line, just us. i am really hoping they will bring us a new modem and router and hopefully that will be the fix. I dont know if you know much about his, but apparently they just upgraded from a DOCSIS1 all the way to a DOCSIS3. We still have a DOCSIS1 i guess. Would that conflict with anything? he said it shouldnt but i dont know. is it possible that a modem could be doing this even though they say the signals are fine?

Comment: I have no knowledge of these but it makes me highly suspicious that you have a device from 2 upgrades ago (old). Techs check the cable signal strength, not your download speed or the bandwidth capacity of your home ethernet set-up.

Comment: They came out and upgraded everything from where they were getting a good signal, they replaced all the cable from there to the house, and upgraded our modem, yet we are still having problems. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too with cable.  Basically its probably everyone being home after work and streaming, and you're sharing the same copper wire going down your street with everyone else and the bandwidth for the neighborhood is just not sufficient.  However they mentioned they went to docsis3, so its worth a shot to insist they give you a new docsis3 router.  After all, why do the upgrade but leave you out?  they also say the signal is fine, but I heard that a few times before they finally installed a powered amplifier in the basement which did improve things.  (I had adelphia before they were bought out.)

Talk to your neighbors, I would not be surprised if they were lying by saying you're the only one complaining.

I should point out that you should be testing your speed using a computer directly connected to the modem to rule out your router as the cause.  Make sure your software firewall is up with its standard configuration (not allow everything for example).

Failing that, I'd look into switching to fios if its available.  If not, start filing complaints with your local regulatory agency.